# How do i create correct Validation from XML to XSD?

Tags: xml, xsd-validation

First time trying XML. I auto generated the XSD but its not correct if i validate XML against XSD. I always get the error => **Element 'LOC': This element is not expected. Expected is ( JOB )**. If i create 2 Datasets for each element it is working but i want to use 1 Dateset for 2 element "Dept" and "EMP".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DB>
    <DEPT>
      <DATASET deptno="10" dname="research">
        <LOC>New York</LOC>
       </DATASET>

     <DATASET deptno="20" dname="research">
      <LOC>DALLAS</LOC>
     </DATASET>

      <DATASET deptno="30" dname="sales">
       <LOC>CHICAGO</LOC>
     </DATASET>

     <DATASET deptno="40" dname="operations">
     <LOC>BOSTON</LOC>
     </DATASET>
   </DEPT>

    <EMP>
    <DATASET empno="7369" ename="smith">
      <JOB>CLERK</JOB>
      <MGR>7902</MGR>
      <HIREDATE>1980-12-17</HIREDATE>
      <SAL>800,00</SAL>
      <COMM>NULL</COMM>
      <DEPTNO>20</DEPTNO>
    </DATASET>

      <DATASET empno="7499" ename="allen">
      <JOB>SALESMAN</JOB>
      <MGR>7698</MGR>
      <HIREDATE>1981-02-20</HIREDATE>
      <SAL>1600,00</SAL>
      <COMM>300,00</COMM>
      <DEPTNO>30</DEPTNO>
      </DATASET>

      <DATASET empno="7521" ename="ward">
      <JOB>SALESMAN</JOB>
      <MGR>7698</MGR>
      <HIREDATE>1981-02-22</HIREDATE>
      <SAL>1250,00</SAL>
      <COMM>500,00</COMM>
      <DEPTNO>30</DEPTNO>
      </DATASET>

      <DATASET empno="7566" ename="jones">
      <JOB>MANAGER</JOB>
      <MGR>7839</MGR>
      <HIREDATE>1981-04-02</HIREDATE>
      <SAL>2975,00</SAL>
      <COMM>NULL</COMM>
      <DEPTNO>20</DEPTNO>
      </DATASET>

   </EMP>
</DB>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="DB">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="DEPT"/>
        <xs:element ref="EMP"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="DEPT">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="DATASET" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="DATASET">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="JOB" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="MGR" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="HIREDATE" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="SAL" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="COMM" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="DEPTNO" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="LOC" type="xs:string"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="deptno" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:attribute name="dname" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:attribute name="empno" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:attribute name="ename" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="EMP">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="DATASET" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: You haven't said what tool you used to auto-generate the XSD. It would be nice to know, because it's clearly made a mess of it. It doesn't seem able to work out that there are two different elements called DATASET with completely different content models, that have to be differentiated by context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following XSD.

**XSD**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="DB">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="DEPT"/>
        <xs:element ref="EMP"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="DEPT">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="DATASET"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="EMP">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="DATASET"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="DATASET">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice>
        <xs:element ref="LOC"/>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element ref="JOB"/>
          <xs:element ref="MGR"/>
          <xs:element ref="HIREDATE"/>
          <xs:element ref="SAL"/>
          <xs:element ref="COMM"/>
          <xs:element ref="DEPTNO"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:choice>
      <xs:attribute name="deptno" type="xs:integer"/>
      <xs:attribute name="dname" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:attribute name="empno" type="xs:integer"/>
      <xs:attribute name="ename" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="LOC" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="JOB" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="MGR" type="xs:integer"/>
  <xs:element name="HIREDATE" type="xs:date"/>
  <xs:element name="SAL" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="COMM" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="DEPTNO" type="xs:integer"/>
</xs:schema>
```